# Why can I retrive an image with absolute path in XAML but it doesn't work behind code?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Trying to understand Assembly, Uri and all of those things and there is some stuff I don't understand and hopefully I can ask them here in one go.

I have a solution that contains two "Assembly's" if I understood it correctly like this.

[Project Assemblies](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4CiBR.png)

Where I want my **FetchResources** to fetch that image and display it on my MainWindow.

It works without a problem when I do it in xaml like this.

[Xaml FetchResources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgNuN.png)

But in behind-code I use the same Uri but for some reason it won't display the image.

```
var uri = new Uri("pack://application,,,/WPF_UserControll_Test;component/Images/71805972.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.UriSource = uri;
testimage.Source = bmi;
```

I'm not sure if I've understood Assembly correctly nor do I understand Uri to the full extent. I've read Microsofts **Pack URIs in WPF** but it's not clear to me how it works.

Why Can I reach the image through XAML but not in behind-code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a colon (:) after "application". Try this:

```
testimage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPF_UserControll_Test;component/Images/71805972.jpg", UriKind.Absolute));
```

And if you don't use the constructor overload that accepts a `Uri`, you should call the `BeginInit()` and `EndInit()` methods before and after you set the `UriSource` property:

```
BitmapImage bmi = new BitmapImage();
bmi.BeginInit();
bmi.UriSource = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPF_UserControll_Test;component/Images/71805972.jpg", UriKind.Absolute);
bmi.EndInit();
testimage.Source = bmi;
```

Comment: It worked. How come I **don't** get an error in my code without the (:) but I get an error with your code without (:) ?

Comment: You won't get an error if you set the UriSource property unless you call the BeginInit() method before.

Comment: Ah okey. Seems "stupid" that it doesn't do that, since this is a easy error. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970069(v=vs.110).aspx)

The following example shows the pack URI for a XAML resource file that is located in the root folder of a referenced, version-specific assembly's project folder.

pack://application:,,,/ReferencedAssembly;v1.0.0.1;component/ResourceFile.xaml